# Bot failing when unit tests included Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, continuous-integration, bots

I am having some issues running unit tests as part of my CI

I the tests run fine on both my dev laptop and the server (mac mini) - however when I create a bot in order to automate this process the bot downloads the repo and completes steps 1-9 but then fails with the error message 
[image: Build service error]

If I remove the unit test from the Bot the Integration completes successfully.

Other examples of this error I have seen, seem to relate to the appropriate version of the simulator not being available on the server - however the server has all available versions and the tests complete fine if I run the build on xcode on the server  - but still fail if I run the bot

Also another SO question pointed to 'Skip install' being set to YES - this is not the case in my unit test target

Any help or suggestions would be appreciate it!

**'**Update**
I found that the integration logs were showing a rogue simulator error
2016-01-27 10:59:55.388 xcodebuild[2649:24495] [MT] DVTDeviceSearch: Search found devices: (
    " {\n\t\tSimDevice: SimDevice : iPhone 4s (BBB75E7C-D96E-4D30-9831-55FC183E11E9) : state={ Shutdown } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s } runtime={ SimRuntime : 8.2 (12D508) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-2 }\n}"
)
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:BBB75E7C-D96E-4D30-9831-55FC183E11E9 }

Running  - xcrun simctl list devices
Didn't expose this simulator - so now I am trying to track it down and remove it - I guess its leftover from an older version of Xcode?

Will post back with my findings - in the meantime if anyone knows a quick way to banish this pain in the arse sim thats causing my tests to fail it would be appreciated!

**'**Update 2**

Still stumped - I ran
xcrun simctl delete BBB75E7C-D96E-4D30-9831-55FC183E11E9
But got the following
Invalid device: BBB75E7C-D96E-4D30-9831-55FC183E11E9

Seems that this sim is cached somewhere - going to try a reboot and if all else fails I think I will have to remove Xcode and redownload :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so it turns out I was barking up the wrong tree completely - it turns out that the issue was that my bot was set to test all simulators - yet I didnt have all simulators installed nor did I need to test on them - so I amended the bot to just run on the OS's I needed and it completed successfully - doh!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I chose an iOS8 simulator for an iOS9 only project.